# Pipelining Generators in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a generator of data in Python and a set of expensive operations that I want to perform to this data. Roughly speaking, for each datum, I want to perform `d(g(h(q(x))))` where `x` is the datum. I want to partially hide the code of performing these operations by using a processing pipeline.

An alternative way of thinking about the problem is that at each stage I want a set of workers reading the results from a pervious stage over a queue, processing and then placing the results on anther queue.

My current solution (which works) is:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool 

class FuncIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, func, base_iterator, pool_size=10):

        self.func = func
        self.base_iterator = base_iterator

        self.pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)

    def __iter__(self):
        aa = self.pool.imap(self.func, self.base_iterator, chunksize=1)

        for item in aa:
            yield item
```

the problem with this solution is that the queue is unbounded; that is, the producer can get arbitrary ahead of the consumer which could lead to unbounded memory usage. I would like to limit the size of the intermediate queues to prevent this.

My first thought is something like this using an explicit `Queue`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Queue

def get_queue(func, f_iter, maxsize=5):
    queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=maxsize)

    def runner(source):
        for entry in source:
            queue.put(func(entry), True)
        queue.put(StopIteration)

    process = ThreadPool.Process(target=runner, args=(f_iter,))
    process.start()
    return queue
```

but then how do I control how many workers are used?

Comment: Not sure about your question. You have a set of operations you intend to chain in a sort of pipeline for readability purposes or there's something else I'm missing? If the next operation depends on the results of the previous one, then using threads is just introducing overhead with no benefits whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I came up with. It takes my original solution, with the unbounded queue problem and uses a `Semaphore`:

```
def _do_sem2(sem, x):
    sem.acquire()
    return x

class FuncIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, func, base_iterator, pool_size=10, queue_size=10):

        self.func = func
        self.base_iterator = base_iterator

        self.pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)
        self.sem = BoundedSemaphore(queue_size)

    def __iter__(self):
        aa = self.pool.imap(self.func, (_do_sem2(self.sem, x) for x in self.base_iterator), chunksize=1)

        for item in aa:
            self.sem.release()
            yield item
```